# Is it possible to make CursorAdapter be set in recycleview, just like ListView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I didn't google out a solution till now to replace listview in my project, because I need to use the cursor linked with the sqlite.

Old way as followed:
`listview.setAdapter(cursorAdapter)` in this way, I can get the cursor to deal with data in database

but now, `recycleview.setAdapter(recycleview.adapter)` it doesn't recognize the adapter extending BaseAdapter

so anyone can give me a hand?

Comment: See my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/27732748/1371730

Nice trick :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the recyclerview with a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517855/using-the-recyclerview-with-a-database)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new `RecyclerView` works with a new `RecyclerView.Adapter` base class. 
So it doesn't work with the `CursorAdapter`.

Currently there is **no default implementation** of `RecyclerView.Adapter` available.

May be with the official release, Google will add it.

Comment: yes, I found one solution in github, but the official release will be better in various aspects, I'd better wait.

Comment: @machinezhou Can you share the github project?

Comment: @josedlujan here is the link of github project https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59

Answer (score 31):

Implementing it yourself is actually quite simple:

```
public class CursorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>{

    Cursor dataCursor;

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (dataCursor == null) ? 0 : dataCursor.getCount();
    }


    public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        Cursor old = swapCursor(cursor);
        if (old != null) {
          old.close();
        }
      }

     public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        if (dataCursor == cursor) {
          return null;
        }
        Cursor oldCursor = dataCursor;
        this.dataCursor = cursor;
        if (cursor != null) {
          this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return oldCursor;
      }

    private Object getItem(int position) {
        dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        // Load data from dataCursor and return it...
      }

}
```

Comment: eh, it's not what I mean buddy, I indeed found a project on github later in which cursorAdapter is implemented by the developer himself.But it's not that easy and I'm not sure if it will come out a bug or something unexpected. So due to my own ability and stability concern, I'd rather wait for the official release.

Comment: @machinezhou I don't think they are going to add an official release for it, so far this has been working flawlessly for me

Comment: The feeling I get is that there isn't going to be an official implementation owing to the "no DB work on the UI thread" vibe they've been pushing since CursorLoader. 

Anyways, as to the solution here, going on other implementations I've seen, you might want to check for potential errors caused by moving the cursor or cursor state. The implementations I've seen so far just throw exceptions in this case, which seems ungraceful to me.

Comment: I'm surprised, but this simple solution worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: tried and onBindViewHolder is called as I get logs but nothing is displayed

Comment: @ingsaurabh If onBindViewHolder is being called then the adapter does have some data backing it. Perhaps your method of pulling data from the cursor isn't functioning as expected? If you're still having issues post up a separate question and I can give you a hand.

Comment: @nyx thanks I solved the problem, issue is not with adapter but some dumb mistake I had done in my code