# Using the recyclerview with a database

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-recyclerview

> Currently there is no default implementation of RecyclerView.Adapter available.
>
> May be with the official release, Google will add it.

Since there is no support for `CursorAdapter` with the `RecyclerView` currently, how can we use a `RecyclerView` with a database ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

If you are running a query with a `CursorLoader` and you want `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`.

You can try my `CursorRecyclerViewAdapter`: [CursorAdapter in RecyclerView](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59)

Comment: @skyfishjy worked for me! thanks for putting this together. saved me some time!

Comment: The code works but not the animations upon deleting and inserting because the method registerDataSetObserver of the Cursor class doesn't identify which element has changed exactly. So every time the content provider changes the recyclerview is loaded completely via [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()), and this is the essence of the RecyclerView.

Comment: What would be the drawback of just passing the cursor to the adapter via the constructor and just using cursor.moveToPosition() in onBindViewHolder(), to get the relevant data ?

Comment: Don't you have to implement `onCreateViewHolder()` in the CursorRecyclerViewAdapter class?

Comment: Suggestion: Call swapCursor() from the constructor, so you dont have to repeat yourself there

Comment: @skyfishjy  How can i extend this to recyclerview that has multiple viewTypes

Comment: @francas Animations work fine if you set `setHasStableIds(true)`

Comment: @alders have you made any other change besides the setHasTableIds? I have tried that as well, the ID's do match and everytime I swap the cursor the list goes back to top.

Comment: Same for me. It goes to the top even with sethasstableid

Comment: @Gautam That is what I did originally. I tried this to see if it improved loading and lost a day finding out it was actually rather unreliable.

Answer (score 92):

My solution was to hold a CursorAdapter member in my recyclerView.Adapter implementation. Then passing all the handling of creating the new view & binding it to the cursor adapter, something like this:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    // Because RecyclerView.Adapter in its current form doesn't natively 
    // support cursors, we wrap a CursorAdapter that will do all the job
    // for us.
    CursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

    Context mContext;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {

        mContext = context;

        mCursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(mContext, c, 0) {

            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                // Inflate the view here
            }

            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                // Binding operations
            }
        };
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View v1;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            v1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.v1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCursorAdapter.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Passing the binding operation to cursor loader
        mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position); //EDITED: added this line as suggested in the comments below, thanks :)
        mCursorAdapter.bindView(holder.itemView, mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor());

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Passing the inflater job to the cursor-adapter
        View v = mCursorAdapter.newView(mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor(), parent);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it works for me, I just had to add one line into onBindViewHolder: 'mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position)' before calling bindView() on mCursorAdapter

Comment: @nbtk Why not to hold a Cursor instead of a CursorAdapter? As I understand, you don't use any of capabilities of CursorAdapter.

Comment: @nbtk with regard to your solution. in the ViewHolder constructor, do you call findViewById for all the views  and populate there or you do that in the bindView of the CursorAdapter?  the v1 = itemView.findViewbyId(R.id.v1); was just for illustrationof a RecyclerView and you don't really do it there. correct?..

Comment: @MyDogTom - I don't hold a Cursor, because you need to clear it when your'e done, and setting it to NULL is not enough. The CursorAdapter takes care of this perfectly.

Comment: @manuelJ - I do not poplate in the ViewHolder constructor, because it is called in the onCreateViewHolder. I just keep the reference of the view itself in Holder.v1, so I can access it later, and therefore I used 'findViewById'. I populate in bindView - notice that I passed the holder.ItemView.

Comment: Does this mean that you still need to 'view.findViewById' in your CursorAdapter#bindView to setup view with data?

Comment: No, just binding: view.setText(...) for example. The inflation is made in the newView

Comment: @nbtk any idea how to get the current position in the data set. I keep getting wrong positions from the cursor.getPosition() or holder.getAdapterPosition();

Comment: @nbtk I do think you still need `findViewById()`. What if your `ViewHolder` view has multiple elements?

Comment: @McAdam331 you are correct, I brought general guideline example :)

Comment: @nbtk I really liked this idea, and I've been playing with it ever since. I tried abstracting it a bit and built a library, that's not 100% where I want it to be yet but it gets the job done. Would you be interested in checking it out? If you have a github I'd be happy to credit you with the inspiration. https://github.com/androidessence/RecyclerViewCursorAdapter

Comment: @nbtk : What a great trick ! But how can i swapCursor() for MyRecyclerAdapter ?

Comment: @anh.tuan : the same way: you create a wrapper method in the recycler adapter which calls mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(...) directly.

Comment: Is it possible to implement dataset changes to be displayed by using inbuilt framework with this method.

Comment: @nbtk Do the following to refresh your view with new data:`public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor){
        mCursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`

Comment: @McAdam331 is it still relevant?

Comment: @Cijo I didn't quite understand your question, the dataset is updated with the mCursorAdapter...

Comment: @Cijo It is working but what you wrote is taking care only for the mCursorAdapter, you also have to notifyDataSetChanged for the wrapping adapter, like 'this.notifyDataSetChanged()'

Comment: @nbtk What i mean is when we use this CursorAdapter with a Loader, in order for the loader to detect and pass on any updates to data in database caused by other codes, changeCursor will work like a charm. Call it from onLoadFinished method of loader.

Comment: @nbtk I haven't updated the library or checked in a while, but AFAIK it will still work.

Comment: @nbtk Thanks for reminding me about it - I've updated the README to include this answer as inspiration. If you have a personal github profile or website you'd like me to link to, feel free to let me know or submit a PR yourself. :)

Comment: This is the best answer for me as I have native ads so this only works as it supports multiple view types so you rock it mate :)

Comment: Have there been changes to the Android platform that make this four year old answer less optimal that it once was?

Comment: @Dale I implemented it today without issue.

Comment: @blueware Could you please share some code on how to extend this library for multiple views?

Answer (score 47):

Since your question says "How to use `RecyclerView` with a database" and you are not being specific whether you want SQLite or anything else with the `RecyclerView`, I'll give you a solution that is highly optimal. I'll be using *Realm* as database and let you display all the data inside your `RecyclerView`. It has asynchronous query support as well without using `Loaders` or `AsyncTask`.

**Why realm?** 
[image: realm.io performance Android]

**Step 1**

Add the gradle dependency for Realm , the dependency for the latest version is found [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

**Step 2**

Create your model class, for example, lets say something simple like `Data` which has 2 fields, a string to be displayed inside the `RecyclerView` row and a timestamp which will be used as itemId for allowing the `RecyclerView` to animate items. Notice that I extend `RealmObject` below because of which your `Data` class will be stored as a table and all your properties will stored as columns of that table `Data`. I have marked the data text as primary key in my case since I don't want a string to be added more than once. But if you prefer having duplicates, then make the timestamp as the @PrimaryKey. You can have a table without a primary key but it will cause problems if you try updating the row after creating it. A composite primary key at the time of writing this answer is not supported by Realm.

```
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

public class Data extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private String data;

//The time when this item was added to the database
private long timestamp;

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
}
```

**Step 3**

Create your layout for how a single row should appear inside the `RecyclerView`. 
The layout for a single row item inside our *`Adapter`* is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="Data"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Notice that I have kept a `FrameLayout` as root even though I have a `TextView` inside. I plan to add more items in this layout and hence made it flexible for now :)

For the curious people out there, this is how a single item looks currently.
[image: single item row layout inside RecyclerView]

**Step 4**

Create your `RecyclerView.Adapter` implementation. In this case, the data source object is a special object called `RealmResults` which is basically a LIVE `ArrayList`, in other words, as items are added or removed from your table, this `RealmResults` object auto updates.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmResults;
import slidenerd.vivz.realmrecycler.R;
import slidenerd.vivz.realmrecycler.model.Data;

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.DataHolder> {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Realm mRealm;
private RealmResults<Data> mResults;

public DataAdapter(Context context, Realm realm, RealmResults<Data> results) {
    mRealm = realm;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    setResults(results);
}

public Data getItem(int position) {
    return mResults.get(position);
}

@Override
public DataHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_data, parent, false);
    DataHolder dataHolder = new DataHolder(view);
    return dataHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataHolder holder, int position) {
    Data data = mResults.get(position);
    holder.setData(data.getData());
}

public void setResults(RealmResults<Data> results) {
    mResults = results;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mResults.get(position).getTimestamp();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mResults.size();
}

public void add(String text) {

    //Create a new object that contains the data we want to add
    Data data = new Data();
    data.setData(text);

    //Set the timestamp of creation of this object as the current time
    data.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    //Start a transaction
    mRealm.beginTransaction();

    //Copy or update the object if it already exists, update is possible only if your table has a primary key
    mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(data);

    //Commit the transaction
    mRealm.commitTransaction();

    //Tell the Adapter to update what it shows.
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void remove(int position) {

    //Start a transaction
    mRealm.beginTransaction();

    //Remove the item from the desired position
    mResults.remove(position);

    //Commit the transaction
    mRealm.commitTransaction();

    //Tell the Adapter to update what it shows
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public static class DataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView area;

    public DataHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        area = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.area);
    }

    public void setData(String text) {
        area.setText(text);
    }
}
}
```

Notice that I am calling `notifyItemRemoved` with the position at which the removal happened but I DON'T call `notifyItemInserted` or `notifyItemRangeChanged` because there is no direct way to know which position the item was inserted into the database since Realm entries are not stored in an ordered fashion. The `RealmResults` object auto updates whenever a new item is added, modified or removed from the database so we call `notifyDataSetChanged` while adding and inserting bulk entries. At this point, you are probably concerned about the animations that won't be triggered because you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged` in place of `notifyXXX` methods. That is exactly why I have the `getItemId` method return the timestamp for each row from the results object. Animation is achieved in 2 steps with `notifyDataSetChanged` if you call `setHasStableIds(true)` and then override `getItemId` to provide something other than just the position.

**Step 5**

Lets add the `RecyclerView` to our `Activity` or `Fragment`. In my case, I am using an `Activity`. The layout file containing the `RecyclerView` is pretty trivial and would look something like this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/recycler"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

I have added an `app:layout_behavior` since my `RecyclerView` goes inside a `CoordinatorLayout` which I have not posted in this answer for brevity.

**Step 6**

Construct the `RecyclerView` in code and supply the data it needs. Create and initialise a Realm object inside `onCreate` and close it inside `onDestroy` pretty much like closing an `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance. At the simplest your `onCreate` inside the `Activity` will look like this. The `initUi` method is where all the magic happens. I open an instance of Realm inside `onCreate`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRealm = Realm.getInstance(this);
    initUi();
}

private void initUi() {

    //Asynchronous query
    RealmResults<Data> mResults = mRealm.where(Data.class).findAllSortedAsync("data");

    //Tell me when the results are loaded so that I can tell my Adapter to update what it shows
    mResults.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange() {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "onChange triggered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new DataAdapter(this, mRealm, mResults);

    //Set the Adapter to use timestamp as the item id for each row from our database
    mAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Notice that in the first step, I query Realm to give me all objects from the `Data` class sorted by their variable name called data in an asynchronous manner. This gives me a `RealmResults` object with 0 items on the main thread which I am setting on the `Adapter`. I added a `RealmChangeListener` to be notified when the data has finished loading from the background thread where I call `notifyDataSetChanged` with my `Adapter`. I have also called `setHasStableIds` to true to let the `RecyclerView.Adapter` implementation keep track of items that are added, removed or modified. The `onDestroy` for my `Activity` closes the Realm instance

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mRealm.close();
}
```

This method `initUi` can be called inside `onCreate` of your `Activity` or `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated` of your `Fragment`. Notice the following things.

**Step 7**

BAM! There is data from database inside your `RecyclerView` asynchonously loaded without `CursorLoader`, `CursorAdapter`, `SQLiteOpenHelper` with animations. The GIF image shown here is kinda laggy but the animations are happening when you add items or remove them.

[image: data from database inside RecyclerView]

Comment: Thanks for providing comprehensive example. I have few questions. I want to store bitmap in realm is it possible? if yes, what would be the column type and how to store and retrieve it?

Comment: @Rakesh never store images inside any database, always store it in your file system and store the uri of the image in database

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I am creating an app where I want to store images for my contact. If I am storing on filesystem there could hundreds of images. How would I manage those images on filesystem?

Comment: FWIW, including a graph of Realm's performance on insert is pretty irrelevant to a question about recyclerviews (which will inevitably be about retrieval)

Comment: Given the toolbar says **Vivz**, is this a @slidenerd solution?

Comment: "ContentProviders" - why not? you can implement it wherever you want, its just a super neat and clean abstraction of ORM

Comment: This the best answer i`v ever came across over the web, Kudos!!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement all the required methods yourself. I recently made my own implementation by just copy pasting code from CursorAdapter.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

        protected boolean mDataValid;
        protected boolean mAutoRequery;
        protected Cursor mCursor;
        protected Context mContext;
        protected int mRowIDColumn;
        protected ChangeObserver mChangeObserver;
        protected DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver;
        protected FilterQueryProvider mFilterQueryProvider;
        public static final int FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY = 0x01;
        public static final int FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER = 0x02;

        public Cursor getCursor() {
            return mCursor;
        }

        //Recommended
        public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
            init(context, c, flags);
        }

        public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
            init(context, c, FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY);
        }

        public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
            init(context, c, autoRequery ? FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY : FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        }

        void init(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
            if ((flags & FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY) == FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY) {
                flags |= FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER;
                mAutoRequery = true;
            } else {
                mAutoRequery = false;
            }
            boolean cursorPresent = c != null;
            mCursor = c;
            mDataValid = cursorPresent;
            mContext = context;
            mRowIDColumn = cursorPresent ? c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id") : -1;
            if ((flags & FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER) == FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER) {
                mChangeObserver = new ChangeObserver();
                mDataSetObserver = new MyDataSetObserver();
            } else {
                mChangeObserver = null;
                mDataSetObserver = null;
            }

            if (cursorPresent) {
                if (mChangeObserver != null) c.registerContentObserver(mChangeObserver);
                if (mDataSetObserver != null) c.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
            }
        }

        // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent,
                                             int viewType) {
            // create a new view
            final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view, mCursor, new ViewHolder.IMyViewHolderClicks() {

                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onClick(Cursor cursor) {
                    Log.e("Item :", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabaseHelper.MW_NAAM)));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(TasksListFragment.this.getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_PARAM_ID, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabaseHelper.MW_ID)));

                    ActivityOptions activityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                            TasksListFragment.this.getActivity(),

                            // Now we provide a list of Pair items which contain the view we can transitioning
                            // from, and the name of the view it is transitioning to, in the launched activity
                            new Pair<View, String>(
                                    view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_item),
                                    DetailActivity.VIEW_NAME_HEADER_IMAGE),
                            new Pair<View, String>(
                                    view.findViewById(R.id.textview_name),
                                    DetailActivity.VIEW_NAME_HEADER_TITLE)
                    );

                    // Now we can start the Activity, providing the activity options as a bundle
                    startActivity(intent, activityOptions.toBundle());
                    // END_INCLUDE(start_activity)
                }
            });
            return vh;
        }

        // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            // - get element from your dataset at this position
            // - replace the contents of the view with that element
            final Cursor cursor = getItem(position);

            holder.mTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabaseHelper.MW_NAAM)));
            holder.mImageView.setTransitionName("grid:image:" + cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabaseHelper.MW_ID)));
            holder.mTextView.setTransitionName("grid:name:" + cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabaseHelper.MW_ID)));
        }

        //@Override
        // public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        //     return view;
        // }

        // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return getCount();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
                return mCursor.getCount();
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public Cursor getItem(int position) {
            if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
                return mCursor;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
                if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                    return mCursor.getLong(mRowIDColumn);
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
            if (newCursor == mCursor) {
                return null;
            }
            Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
            if (oldCursor != null) {
                if (mChangeObserver != null) oldCursor.unregisterContentObserver(mChangeObserver);
                if (mDataSetObserver != null) oldCursor.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
            }
            mCursor = newCursor;
            if (newCursor != null) {
                if (mChangeObserver != null) newCursor.registerContentObserver(mChangeObserver);
                if (mDataSetObserver != null) newCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
                mRowIDColumn = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
                mDataValid = true;
                // notify the observers about the new cursor
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                mRowIDColumn = -1;
                mDataValid = false;
                // notify the observers about the lack of a data set
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
            return oldCursor;
        }

        public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
            Cursor old = swapCursor(cursor);
            if (old != null) {
                old.close();
            }
        }

        public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
            return cursor == null ? "" : cursor.toString();
        }

        public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (mFilterQueryProvider != null) {
                return mFilterQueryProvider.runQuery(constraint);
            }
            return mCursor;
        }


        public FilterQueryProvider getFilterQueryProvider() {
            return mFilterQueryProvider;
        }

        public void setFilterQueryProvider(FilterQueryProvider filterQueryProvider) {
            mFilterQueryProvider = filterQueryProvider;
        }

        protected void onContentChanged() {
            if (mAutoRequery && mCursor != null && !mCursor.isClosed()) {
                if (false) Log.v("Cursor", "Auto requerying " + mCursor + " due to update");
                mDataValid = mCursor.requery();
            }
        }

        private class ChangeObserver extends ContentObserver {
            public ChangeObserver() {
                super(new Handler());
            }

            @Override
            public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                onContentChanged();
            }
        }

        private class MyDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                mDataValid = true;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onInvalidated() {
                mDataValid = false;
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }


        private final DataSetObservable mDataSetObservable = new DataSetObservable();

        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            mDataSetObservable.registerObserver(observer);
        }

        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            mDataSetObservable.unregisterObserver(observer);
        }

        public void notifyDataSetInvalidated() {
            mDataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So where's the Loader in this class?

Comment: The loader will use this adapter. See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html for an example of how to use a loader. In this example SimpleCursorAdapter would be MyAdapter

Comment: What do you mean SimpleCursorAdapter?  You are extending RecyclerView.Adapter.

Comment: I mean that if you see SimpleCursorAdapter in the example, you can put MyAdapter in place of that. It does not matter what adapter you extend as long as it has the swapcursor method and some other methods.

Comment: Seems a bit of over coding if compared to @nbtk 's answer above.

Comment: Still has the problem of using `notifyDataSetChanged()` every time any change happens.  This removes the automatic animations that RecyclerView provides and is terribly inefficient.  You might as well use ListView.

Answer (score 1):

I made a [RecyclerViewCursorAdapter](https://github.com/qvga/RecyclerViewCursorAdapter) using a [SortedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.html) as backend, extending [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

Can be used with [SQLiteCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html) and [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/Loader.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just another answer, since I did not like the accepted one (which imo has not an intuitive usage).

The following is my own implementation, which is very similar to (and partially inspired by) `SimpleCursorAdapter`:

```
public class RecyclerViewSimpleCursorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private int mLayout;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private String[] mFrom;
    private int[] mTo;

    private boolean mAutoRequery;
    private ContentObserver mContentObserver;

    /**
     * Standard constructor.
     *
     * @param layout resource identifier of a layout file that defines the views for this list item. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "to"
     * @param c      The database cursor. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
     * @param from   A list of column names representing the data to bind to the UI. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
     * @param to     The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. These should all be TextViews and ImageViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
     */
    public RecyclerViewSimpleCursorAdapter(int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, boolean autoRequery) {
        mLayout = layout;
        mCursor = c;
        mFrom = from;
        mTo = to;
        mAutoRequery = autoRequery;

        if (mAutoRequery) {
            initializeContentObserver();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(mLayout, parent, false)
        ) {
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

        if (mFrom == null || mTo == null)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < mFrom.length && i < mTo.length; i++) {
            String from = mFrom[i];
            int columnIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(from);
            String value = mCursor.getString(columnIndex);
            View view = holder.itemView.findViewById(mTo[i]);

            if (view instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) view).setText(value);
            } else if (view instanceof ImageView) {
                try {
                    ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(value));
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    ((ImageView) view).setImageURI(Uri.parse(value));
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException(view.getClass().getName() + " is not a view that can be bound by this RecyclerViewSimpleCursorAdapter");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCursor  != null ? mCursor.getCount() : 0;
    }

    private void initializeContentObserver() {
        mContentObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        mCursor.registerContentObserver(mContentObserver);
    }

    /**
     * Change the underlying cursor to a new cursor. If there is an existing cursor it will be closed.
     *
     * @param cursor The new cursor to be used
     */
    public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
        if (mAutoRequery) {
            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.unregisterContentObserver(mContentObserver);
            }

            mContentObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
                @Override
                public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };

            mCursor = cursor;
            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.registerContentObserver(mContentObserver);
            }
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (oldCursor != null && oldCursor != mCursor) {
            oldCursor.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Change the cursor and change the column-to-view mappings at the same time.
     *
     * @param cursor The database cursor. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
     * @param from A list of column names representing the data to bind to the UI. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
     * @param to The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. These should all be TextViews or ImageViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
     */
    public void changeCursorAndColumns(Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to) {
        mFrom = from;
        mTo = to;
        changeCursor(cursor);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the cursor.
     * @return the cursor
     */
    public Cursor getCursor() {
        return mCursor;
    }
}
```

You may modify it for other particular usages, but having a cursor it works just as `SimpleCursorAdapter` does, only with a `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving data from DB and store in a list, maybe it should be something like this:

```
    dbHelper = new BooksDbAdapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();
    //Clean all data
    dbHelper.deleteAllZist();
    //Add some data
    dbHelper.insertSomeRecords();
    List<String> mylist = dbHelper.getArrayColumn(3);
```

add data to recyclerview

```
list = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
 Integer i=0;
    for (String lst : mylist) {
        list.add(i++, new DataObject(lst,
                "The RecyclerView widget is a more advanced and flexible 
               version of ListView."));
    }

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    myRecAdapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(list, Zist1ChapterActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my implementation of cursoradapter for a recyclerview.
It supports OnItemClickListener, OnLongItemClickListener, OnfooterClickListener, Sections, and footer. **Does not support**, Header, onHeaderClickListner, fast scroller, sticky header or sticky sections.

Just extend this adapter and create your own adapter. Override the methods provided. and pass the cursor from OnCursorLoadFinished method.if the adapter is already created then swapCursor()

```
package com.tracker.paisa;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * @author Rahul Upadhyay (https://github.com/devDroidRaul)
 * Supports footer
 * Onitemclicklistener, OnItemLongClickListener, OnFooterClickListener
 * Supports Sections.
 *
 * Does Not support,Header, OnHeaderClickListener, FastScroller, StickySection (this can b done with item decor)
 * Pull requests are welcome for improvements.
 *
 * Override this to give logic to place subheaders between items.
 * public abstract boolean onPlaceSubheaderBetweenItems(int position);
 *
 * create seperate viewHolders for item, subheaders and footer. and return required views.
 *
 * @Override below methods for individual item type.
 * public abstract VH onCreateItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);
 * public abstract SH onCreateSubheaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);
 * public abstract FH onCreateFooterViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);
 *
 * Bind your views with data here.
 * @Override below methods to bind data to individual item types.
 * public abstract void onBindSubHeaderViewHolder(SH holder, Cursor cursor);
 * public abstract void onBindItemViewHolder(VH holder, Cursor cursor);
 * public abstract void onBindFooterViewHolder(FH holder, int itemPosition);
 *
 * Item type -1,-2,-3 are reserved, kindly do not pass them in getItemViewType.
 */

public abstract class RecyclerViewCursorAdapter<SH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder, VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder, FH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public static final String TAG = RecyclerViewCursorAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = -1;

    private static final int TYPE_MAIN_HEADER = -2;
    private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = -3;

   // private int headerLayout=0,viewLayout=0;
    boolean createHeader;

    private List<Integer> subheaderPositions = new ArrayList<>();

    private Cursor mCursor;
    private boolean mDataValid,footerRequired=false;
    private int mRowIDColumn;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;



   // public RecyclerViewCursorAdapter() { }

    //constructor
    public RecyclerViewCursorAdapter(Cursor c,boolean footerRequired) {
        setHasStableIds(true);
        swapCursor(c);
        this.footerRequired = footerRequired;

        this.mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }



    // interface for listning click on recycler view;
    public interface OnItemClickedListener{
        void OnItemClick(int id, Object data);

        void onItemLongClick(int id);
    }

    OnItemClickedListener onItemClickedListener;

    public void setOnItemClickedListener(OnItemClickedListener onItemClickedListener) {
        this.onItemClickedListener = onItemClickedListener;
    }

    public interface OnFooterClickedListener{
        void onFooterClick(Object data);
    }

    OnFooterClickedListener onFooterClickedListener;
    public void setOnFooterClickedListener( OnFooterClickedListener onFooterClickedListener){
        this.onFooterClickedListener = onFooterClickedListener;
    }

    public interface OnHeaderClickedListener{
        void onHeaderClick(Object data);
    }

    OnHeaderClickedListener onHeaderClickedListener;
    public void setOnHeaderClickedListener( OnHeaderClickedListener onHeaderClickedListener){
        this.onHeaderClickedListener = onHeaderClickedListener;
    }

    private void initSubheaderPositions() {
        subheaderPositions.clear();

        if(getItemSize() != 0) {
            //TODO:Handle This please.
            //subheaderPositions.add(0);
        } else {
            return;
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < getItemSize(); i++) {
            if(onPlaceSubheaderBetweenItems(i - 1)) {
                subheaderPositions.add(i + subheaderPositions.size());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

            initSubheaderPositions();



    }

    /**
     * Called when adapter needs to know whether to place subheader between two neighboring
     * items.
     *
     * @return true if you want to place subheader between two neighboring
     * items.
     */
    public abstract boolean onPlaceSubheaderBetweenItems(int position);

    public abstract VH onCreateItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

    public abstract SH onCreateSubheaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

    public abstract FH onCreateFooterViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

    public abstract void onBindSubHeaderViewHolder(SH holder, Cursor cursor);

    public abstract void onBindItemViewHolder(VH holder, Cursor cursor);

    public abstract void onBindFooterViewHolder(FH holder, int itemPosition);






    public abstract int getItemSize();

    /**
     * Return the view type of the item at position for the purposes
     * of view recycling.
     * Don't return -1. It's reserved for subheader view type.
     */
    public int getViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public final int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if(isSubheaderOnPosition(position)) {
            return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
        } if(footerRequired && getCursor().getPosition()==(getCursor().getCount()-1)){
            return TYPE_FOOTER;
        }else {
            return getViewType(position);
        }
    }

    public boolean isFooterAdded(){
        return footerRequired;
    }
    @Override
    public final RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d("RVCA-OCVH","create viewholder");
        if(viewType == TYPE_SECTION_HEADER) {
            return onCreateSubheaderViewHolder(parent, viewType);
        } if(footerRequired&&viewType == TYPE_FOOTER){
            return onCreateFooterViewHolder(parent, viewType);
        }else {
            return onCreateItemViewHolder(parent, viewType);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public final void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("RVCA-OBVH","bind viewholder");
        Log.d("RVCA-OBVH","subheader position:"+isSubheaderOnPosition(position));
        if(isSubheaderOnPosition(position)) {
            if (!mDataValid) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot bind viewholder when cursor is in invalid state.");
            }
            if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(getItemPositionForViewHolder(position))) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not move cursor to position " + getItemPositionForViewHolder(position) + " when trying to bind viewholder");
            }

            onBindSubHeaderViewHolder((SH)holder, mCursor);
        }if(footerRequired && position==getItemCount()-1){
            Log.d("RVCA-OBVH","bind footerHolder");
            onBindFooterViewHolder((FH) holder,position);

        } else {
            if (!mDataValid) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot bind viewholder when cursor is in invalid state.");
            }
            if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(getItemPositionForViewHolder(position))) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not move cursor to position " + getItemPositionForViewHolder(position) + " when trying to bind viewholder");
            }
            // if(!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            //   mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            onBindItemViewHolder((VH)holder, mCursor);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public final int getItemCount() {
        return getItemSize() + subheaderPositions.size()+(footerRequired?1:0);
    }

    public void notifyDataChanged() {
        initSubheaderPositions();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void notifyItemInsertedAtPosition(int itemPosition) {
        if (itemPosition == 0) {
            if (getItemCount() == 1 || onPlaceSubheaderBetweenItems(itemPosition)) {
                subheaderPositions.add(0, 0);
                increaseSubheaderPositions(1, 2);
                notifyItemRangeInserted(0, 2);
            } else {
                increaseSubheaderPositions(1, 1);
                notifyItemInserted(1);
            }
        } else if (itemPosition == getItemSize() - 1) {
            if (onPlaceSubheaderBetweenItems(itemPosition - 1)) {
                subheaderPositions.add(getItemCount() - 1);
                notifyItemRangeInserted(getItemCount() - 1, 2);
            } else {
                notifyItemInserted(getItemPositionInRecyclerView(itemPosition));
            }
        } else {
            if (onPlaceSubheaderBetweenItems(itemPosition - 1) && onPlaceSubheaderBetweenItems(itemPosition)) {
                final int itemPositionInRv = getItemPositionInRecyclerView(itemPosition - 1);
                final int countOfSubheadersBeforePosition = getCountOfSubheadersBeforePosition(itemPositionInRv);
                subheaderPositions.add(countOfSubheadersBeforePosition, itemPositionInRv + 1);
                increaseSubheaderPositions(countOfSubheadersBeforePosition + 1, 2);
                notifyItemRangeInserted(itemPositionInRv + 1, 2);
            } else if (onPlaceSubheaderBetweenItems(itemPosition)){
                final int itemPositionInRv = getItemPositionInRecyclerView(itemPosition - 1);
                increaseSubheaderPositions(getCountOfSubheadersBeforePosition(itemPositionInRv), 1);
                notifyItemInserted(itemPositionInRv + 1);
            } else if (onPlaceSubheaderBetweenItems(itemPosition - 1)) {
                final int itemPositionInRv = getItemPositionInRecyclerView(itemPosition);
                increaseSubheaderPositions(getCountOfSubheadersBeforePosition(itemPositionInRv), 1);
                notifyItemInserted(itemPositionInRv);
            } else {
                final int itemPositionInRv = getItemPositionInRecyclerView(itemPosition);
                increaseSubheaderPositions(getCountOfSubheadersBeforePosition(itemPositionInRv), 1);
                notifyItemInserted(itemPositionInRv);
            }
        }
    }

    public void notifyItemChangedAtPosition(int itemPosition) {
        final int itemPositionInRv = getItemPositionInRecyclerView(itemPosition);
        notifyItemChanged(itemPositionInRv);
    }

    public void notifyItemRemovedAtPosition(int itemPosition) {

        final int itemPositionInRv = getItemPositionInRecyclerView(itemPosition);

        for (int i = 1; i < subheaderPositions.size(); i++) {
            final int subheaderPosition = subheaderPositions.get(i);
            if (subheaderPosition > itemPositionInRv) {
                final int previousSubheaderPosition = subheaderPositions.get(i - 1);
                if (subheaderPosition - previousSubheaderPosition == 2) {
                    subheaderPositions.remove(subheaderPositions.indexOf(previousSubheaderPosition));
                    decreaseSubheaderPositions(subheaderPositions.indexOf(subheaderPosition), 2);
                    notifyItemRangeRemoved(itemPositionInRv - 1, 2);
                } else {
                    decreaseSubheaderPositions(subheaderPositions.indexOf(subheaderPosition), 1);
                    notifyItemRemoved(itemPositionInRv);
                }
                return;
            }
        }

        final int lastSubheaderPosition = subheaderPositions.get(subheaderPositions.size() - 1);
        if (itemPositionInRv - lastSubheaderPosition == 1 && getItemCount() == itemPosition + subheaderPositions.size()) {
            subheaderPositions.remove(subheaderPositions.size() - 1);
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(itemPositionInRv - 1, 2);
        } else {
            notifyItemRemoved(itemPositionInRv);
        }
    }

    public void setGridLayoutManager(final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager) {
        gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                if(subheaderPositions.contains(position)) {
                    return gridLayoutManager.getSpanCount();
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isSubheaderOnPosition(int position) {
        return subheaderPositions.contains(position);
    }

    public int getCountOfSubheadersBeforePosition(int position) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int subheaderPosition : subheaderPositions) {
            if(subheaderPosition < position) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public int getItemPositionInRecyclerView(int position) {
        int countOfItems = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < subheaderPositions.size(); i++) {
            final int previousSubheaderPosition = subheaderPositions.get(i - 1);
            final int nextSubheaderPosition = subheaderPositions.get(i);
            countOfItems += nextSubheaderPosition - previousSubheaderPosition - 1;
            if (countOfItems > position) {
                return position + i;
            }
        }
        return position + subheaderPositions.size();
    }

    public int getItemPositionForViewHolder(int viewHolderPosition) {
        return viewHolderPosition - getCountOfSubheadersBeforePosition(viewHolderPosition);
    }

    private void decreaseSubheaderPositions(int startSubheaderPosition, int decreaseNum) {
        for (int i = startSubheaderPosition; i < subheaderPositions.size(); i++) {
            final int subheaderPosition = subheaderPositions.get(i);
            subheaderPositions.set(i, subheaderPosition - decreaseNum);
        }
    }

    private void increaseSubheaderPositions(int startSubheaderPosition, int increaseNum) {
        for (int i = startSubheaderPosition; i < subheaderPositions.size(); i++) {
            final int subheaderPosition = subheaderPositions.get(i);
            subheaderPositions.set(i, subheaderPosition + increaseNum);
        }
    }

    private List<Integer> getSubheaderPositions() {
        return subheaderPositions;
    }

    public int getSubheaderCount() {
        return subheaderPositions.size();
    }

    public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        Log.d("RVCA-SC","swap cursor");
        if (newCursor == mCursor) {
            Log.d("RVCA-SC","same cursor doing nothing");
            return;
        }

        if (newCursor != null) {
            Log.d("RVCA-SC","swap cursor not null");
            mCursor = newCursor;
            mRowIDColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
            mDataValid = true;

            // notify the observers about the new cursor
            notifyDataChanged();
        } else {
            Log.d("RVCA-SC","swap cursor null");
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, getItemCount());
            mCursor = null;
            mRowIDColumn = -1;
            mDataValid = false;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getCursor(){
        return mCursor ;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (isSubheaderOnPosition(position))
            return position;
        else {
            int cursorPosition = getItemPositionForViewHolder(position);
            Cursor cursor = getCursor();
            if (hasOpenCursor() && cursor.moveToPosition(cursorPosition)) {
                return cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            }
            return NO_CURSOR_POSITION;
        }
    }
    public static final int NO_CURSOR_POSITION = -99;

    protected boolean hasOpenCursor() {
        Cursor cursor = getCursor();
        if (cursor == null || cursor.isClosed()) {
            swapCursor(null);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //Methods to do Selection

    public void toggleSelection(int position) {
        selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
    }


    //Remove selected selections
    public void removeSelection() {
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    //Put or delete selected position into SparseBooleanArray
    public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
        if (value)
            mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
        else
            mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);

        // notifyItemChangedAtPosition(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //Get total selected count
    public int getSelectedCount() {
        return mSelectedItemsIds.size();
    }

    //Return all selected ids
    public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
        return mSelectedItemsIds;
    }

    public void setSelectedItemIds(SparseBooleanArray selectedItemIds){
        this.mSelectedItemsIds=selectedItemIds;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest implementation is to use cursor object in the adapter and pass cursor to viewholder constructor for modifying views and change the cursor position in onBindViewholder.

If you are using cursor Loader call the setCursor method in `onLoadfinished()` and passing null in `onLoadReset()`

```
public class PetCursorRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PetCursorRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
Cursor cursor = null;
Context context;

public PetCursorRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

}

public void setCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    this.cursor = cursor;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.catalog_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    this.cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    holder.bindModel(this.cursor);
}

/*   getItemCount() returns the count of videos from the Cursor, or 0 if the
   Cursor is null (mimicking the behavior of CursorAdapter, which also treats
   a null Cursor as merely being one that has no rows)*/
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (cursor == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView name_tv, breed_tv;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
        breed_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.breed_tv);
    }

    public void bindModel(Cursor cursor) {
        int name_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PetsContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME);
        int breed_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PetsContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED);
        name_tv.setText(cursor.getString(name_index));
        String breed = cursor.getString(breed_index);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(breed)) {
            breed = "Unknown Breed";
        }
        breed_tv.setText(breed);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Finally we have an implementation of RecyclerView.Adapter for database/network.

It realised with an Android [Architecture Components](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/):

**Room database:** Database layer on top of SQLite database that takes care of mundane tasks that you used to handle with an `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Database holder that serves as an access point to the underlying SQLite database. The Room database uses the DAO to issue queries to the SQLite database.

**ViewModel:** Provides data to the UI. Acts as a communication center between the Repository and the UI. Hides where the data originates from the UI. ViewModel instances survive Activity/Fragment recreation.

**LiveData:** A data holder class that can be observed. Always holds/caches latest version of data. Notifies its observers when the data has changed. LiveData is lifecycle aware. UI components just observe relevant data and don't stop or resume observation. LiveData automatically manages all of this since it's aware of the relevant lifecycle status changes while observing.

Answer (score -2):

You can use SQLite database to store the details. It is easy to access the data.
You can check my code on github. https://github.com/thiru-wta/ToDo

```
     database = new Database(this);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("To Do List");
    etAddItems = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddItem);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, listData);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            event_name = etAddItems.getText().toString();
            String getname="";

              database.storeEventDetails(event_name);

                 getname = database.getEventDetails(event_name);


            if (getname.length() != 0) {
                listData.add(getname);
                etAddItems.setText("");

                adapter.notifyData(listData);
            }
```

Database methods:

```
    public void storeEventDetails(String event_name, long timerStart) {
    SQLiteDatabase db1 = getWritableDatabase();
    db1.execSQL("insert into '"+event_details_tbl+"' values('" + event_name + "')");
    db1.close();
}
```

get method:

```
     public String getEventDetails(String event_name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db1 = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db1.rawQuery("select * from '"+event_details_tbl+"' where     event_name ='" + event_name + "'", null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    String evName = null;
    if (cur != null) {
        do {
            int eventName = cur.getColumnIndex("event_name");

            String ev_name = cur.getString(eventName);

            evName = ev_name;
        } while (cur.moveToNext());

    }
    cur.close();
    db1.close();
    return evName;

}
```

Answer (score -4):

You have simply to follow these steps:

- In the recycler `view.adapter`, create an ArrayList or an Iterator initialized with a null value.
- Create a method like the ex swapcursor, for example `swapdata(Arraylist<T> data)`.  Inside you give a new values to the array list, iterator or any structure that system can iterate using the integer position int the bindview.  The values of this method are passed in the `onloaderfinished()`.  Then call in just after assignement `notifydatachange()`; these will ask the `RecyclerView` to redraw all the list with new data of the ArrayList.

In the activity or fragment where you are using the loadercalback, create a method that transforms the cursor to an arraylist, or iterator, depending on the data structure chosen in the adapter.

This way you can always use the loadercalback with out blocking the main thread.