# SimpleCursorAdapter for RecyclerView

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-recyclerview

Is there something similar to SimpleCursorAdapter but instead for ListView for RecyclerView? 
Thank you

Comment: yes, see ItemBridgeAdapter

Comment: Thank you, and is there an example anywhere?

Comment: None i am aware of,  you have do it by yourself...

Comment: Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/CursorObjectAdapter.html when constructing your ItemBridgeAdapter

Comment: Ok, I´m going to try

Comment: I need minSdkVersion 17 or more if I want to use this, but I want to use lower versions, so I think I ´m going to use another strategy...

Comment: So implement base RecyclerView.Adapter, its really simple...

Answer (score 0):

You can find one here:
https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b

You can also find other suggestions here:
[Using the recyclerview with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517855/using-the-recyclerview-with-a-database)