# get position of cursor in CursorAdapter wrapped in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-recyclerview

Good day, i am getting information from a database in my application and i have managed to wrap a CursorAdapter into a RecyclerView as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517855/using-the-recyclerview-with-a-database)
But i can't seem to get the position of the switch. i always get back the last item position from the ViewHolder or the Cursor and not the selected position. Here is my Code:

```
public class ActionRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ActionRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    CursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

    Context mContext;

    //Cursor cursor;
    int position;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public ActionRecyclerAdapter(final Context mContext, Cursor cursor) {

        this.mContext = mContext;

        mCursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(mContext,cursor, 0) {

   /*         @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if(convertView == null){
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_list_items, parent, false);
                }
                convertView.setTag(position);
                return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            }*/

            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_list_items, parent, false);

                TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title_id);
                TextView details = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.items_details_id);
                Switch switch = (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.item_switch_id);


                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
                holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

                holder.name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseModule.KEY_NAME)));
                holder.details.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseModule.KEY_TIME)));


                 //position=(Integer) view.getTag();



                holder.switch.setOncheckListener(new Switch.OnCheckListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheck(boolean b) {
                        if(b){
                            //holder.timer_switch.getTag();

                            //position returned is wrong
                            Toast.makeText(context, "item position" + holder.getAdapterPosition() + "is checked",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCursorAdapter.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);
       // holder.setDataPosition(position);
        mCursorAdapter.bindView(holder.itemView, mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor());
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View v = mCursorAdapter.newView(mContext,mCursorAdapter.getCursor(),parent);
       // ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
         holder = new ViewHolder(v);
             v.setTag(holder);
        return holder;
    }



    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View v1;
        TextView name;
        TextView details;
        Switch switch;
        int position;



        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //v1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.v1);
        }

       // public void setDataPosition(int position){
       //     this.position = position;
      //  }

      //  public int getDataPosition(){
        //    return position;
        //}
    }
}
```

I have tried to even set the position in the Viewholder but no luck. ANy ideas how i can get the current position from the Viewholder or the cursor. Many Thanks

Comment: "ANy ideas how i can get the current position from the Viewholder " ? did you read `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` javadocs?

Comment: @pskink yes i did. but i keep getting the wrong position. Not sure whether i am passing the binding to bindView is causing the problem.

Comment: use this: https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59 or this:   https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b or any similar adapter

Comment: @pskink sorry for the very late response. thanks works well!

Comment: you owe me one beer then because of that late response... ;)