# How to add data from a database to a recycler view using a cursor adapter?

Tags: java, android

So I have tried implementing my database with a recycler view and cursoradapter, but I am getting errors. I can not understand them well so I dont know if I did not implement the adapter right or if it is something else. Here are the java files:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.nick.mowen.receiptmanager.LOCATION";
    public String Places[];
    public RecyclerView RV;
    private RVAdapter adapter;
    Cursor mCursor;
    ManagerDatabaseAdapter managerDatabaseAdapter;
    List<MainInfo> mainInfo = new ArrayList<MainInfo>();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private Context activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        managerDatabaseAdapter = new ManagerDatabaseAdapter(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adapter = new RVAdapter(getActivity(), managerDatabaseAdapter.getTheCursor());
        RV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainV);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        RV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RV.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
      //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, li)
        return true;
    }

    public static void getData () {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,true);
            startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView userText= (TextView) view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }*/

    public void addInstance(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,LocationAdder.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,true);
        startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
    }

    public Context getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }
}
```

Here is the recycler view adapter:

```
public class RVAdapter extends Adapter<RVAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    CursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;
    Context mContext;
    //Cursor cursor;
    //public Cursor mCursor;
    MainInfo mainInfo;
    ManagerDatabaseAdapter.ManagerHelper managerHelper;
    public ManagerDatabaseAdapter managerDatabaseAdapter;
   // public List<MainInfo> mainInfoList = Collections.emptyList();

    public RVAdapter (Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        mContext = context;
        mCursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(mContext, cursor, 0) {
            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                //Cursor mCursor = getCursor();

                final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

                int nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndex("Codes");
                String name = cursor.getString(nameCol);

                TextView nameText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainV);
                if (nameText != null) {
                    nameText.setText(name);
                }
                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                int nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndex("Code");
                String name = cursor.getString(nameCol);
                TextView nameText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainV);
                if (nameText != null) {
                    nameText.setText(name);
                }
            }
        };
        //this.mainInfoList = mainInfoList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mCursorAdapter.newView(mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor(), parent);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int i) {
        /*MainInfo mainInfo = mainInfoList.get(i);
        holder.Title.setText(mainInfo.get_Title());
        holder.Body.setText(mainInfo.get_SubT());*/
        mCursorAdapter.bindView(holder.itemView, mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //return mainInfoList.size();
        return mCursorAdapter.getCount();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView Title;

         MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Row_Header);
            //Body = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Row_Footer);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the method to get the cursor:

```
public Cursor getTheCursor() {
        String[] columns = {ManagerHelper.UID,ManagerHelper.NAME,ManagerHelper.CODE};
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(ManagerHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        return mCursor;
    }
```

And finally here is the error I am getting:

[image: Error]

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b)

Comment: I am not sure if its your compulsion to use CursorAdapter or you asked the question merely because you werent aware of alternatives, if thats the case, check my answer here on how to populate recyclerview from database with realm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517855/using-the-recyclerview-with-a-database/33568015#33568015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in onCreate you're using the method getActivity() but you're never initializing the activity object.

Please try to change your onCreate to something like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);            
        managerDatabaseAdapter = new ManagerDatabaseAdapter(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adapter = new RVAdapter(this, managerDatabaseAdapter.getTheCursor());
        RV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainV);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        RV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RV.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

That should fix your NPE and you can see what other parts are missing. And remove the getActivity() method, you don't need that in an Activity it is used on a Fragment, so I supposed you copied that code from a Fragment implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a query with a CursorLoader and you want RecyclerView instead of ListView.

You can try my CursorRecyclerViewAdapter [CursorAdapter in RecyclerView](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59)

And also visit this reference link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26673645/3678308)

Comment: Ok, I saw that before but I did not understand what the MyListItem fromCursor is supposed to do. Thanks.