# How can I use a RecyclerView with a database?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `ListView` where I displayed data from a database using mysql and json but by doing some research I found the `RecyclerView` widget is a more advanced and flexible version of `ListView`. This widget is a container for displaying large data sets and that with the `RecyclerView` I can have a result like this. So how I can correct my code? How can I extract an image from a database and fetch it into the `RecyclerView`

[image]

Here's how I've done it in `ListView`

```
private void showarticles(String json){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            JSONArray result = new JSONArray(json);

            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jo.getString("Nom");
                String ref = jo.getString("Description");
                HashMap<String,String> articles= new HashMap<>();
                articles.put("name",name);
                articles.put("ref",ref);
                list.add(articles);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), list, R.layout.list_row2,
                new String[]{"name","ref"},
                new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.description});

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void getJSON() {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Téléchargement", "Veuillez patientez...", false, false);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                JSON_STRING = s;
                showarticles(s);
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendGetRequest(URL);
                return s;
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute();
    }
```

Update

```
public class recyclerFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
ListAdapter adapter;
private String JSON_STRING;
public static final String URL = "http://aaaa.com/Back/getArticles.php";
private MyAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_fragment, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.my_list);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(10));
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(null);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    getJSON();
return rootview;
}
private void showarticles(String json){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            JSONArray result = new JSONArray(json);

            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jo.getString("Nom");
                String ref = jo.getString("Description");
                HashMap<String,String> articles= new HashMap<>();
                articles.put("name",name);
                articles.put("ref",ref);
                list.add(articles);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            getActivity(), list, R.layout.list_row2,
            new String[]{"name","ref"},
            new int[]{R.id.nom, R.id.email2});

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
private void getJSON() {
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Téléchargement", "Veuillez patientez...", false, false);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            JSON_STRING = s;
            showEmployee(s);
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequest(URL);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute();
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ViewProduit.class);
    HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String tid = map.get("ref").toString();
    intent.putExtra("ref", tid);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

```
Error:(31, 27) error: cannot find symbol variable myArrayList
Error:(76, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable myArrayList
Error:(77, 20) error: cannot find symbol variable myArrayList
Error:(41, 45) error: cannot find symbol class SpacesItemDecoration
Error:(44, 20) error: constructor MyAdapter in class MyAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: <null>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Error:(74, 20) error: incompatible types: SimpleAdapter cannot be converted to MyAdapter
Error:(106, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the recyclerview with a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517855/using-the-recyclerview-with-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `RecyclerView` in your layout first.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Now if you're in an `Activity`, lets initialize your `RecyclerView` along with the `LayoutManager`. In your case you need to have a `GridLayoutManager`

```
// Declare them first
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MyAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
```

Initialize the items inside your `onCreate` function and set the `Adapter` here.

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(10));
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mAdapter = new MyAdapter();
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Now get your `ArrayList` prepared to pass it in the `Adapter` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to populate the `RecyclerView` with the items you want to show.

So here you go with your custom `Adapter`

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public MyAdapter() {
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // Declare the items in each row 
        private TextView myTextView;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // Initialize the items here
            myTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
        }

        public void bindView(int pos) {
            // Set the items here with specific array elements you have
            String text = myArrayList.get(pos);
            myTextView.setText(text);
        }
    }

    // Now define the viewholder for Normal list item
    public class NormalViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        public NormalViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO: Here's what you want to do when your list item is clicked
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v;

        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);

        NormalViewHolder vh = new NormalViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            if (holder instanceof NormalViewHolder) {
                NormalViewHolder vh = (NormalViewHolder) holder;
                vh.bindView(position);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (myArrayList != null)
            return myArrayList.size();
        else return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
}
```

Declare `myArrayList` as global and populate `myArrayList` with the elements you want and customize the `bindView` as you want. When you are done with populating the `myArrayList` call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on your `Adapter` like `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

**Update**

So here's I'm taking your updated code and modifying as much as possible. The code might have errors, but I think after you get it modified you can do the rest by yourself.

```
public class recyclerFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private String JSON_STRING;
    public static final String URL = "http://aaaa.com/Back/getArticles.php";
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    // Declare the list globally
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_fragment, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.my_list);

        // Initialize the list here 
        list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Initialize other items
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(10));
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        getJSON();

        return rootview;
    }

    private void showarticles(String json){
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

            try {
                JSONArray result = new JSONArray(json);

                for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jo.getString("Nom");
                    String ref = jo.getString("Description");
                    HashMap<String,String> articles= new HashMap<>();
                    articles.put("name",name);
                    articles.put("ref",ref);
                    list.add(articles);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        // Here you can call notifyDataSetChanged in your Adapter. As you've the dataset ready now. 
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void getJSON() {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Téléchargement", "Veuillez patientez...", false, false);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                JSON_STRING = s;
                showEmployee(s);
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendGetRequest(URL);
                return s;
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute();
    }

    // Here you write your custom Adapter class 
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        public MyAdapter() {
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            // Declare the items in each row 
            private Button myButton;

            public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                // Initialize the items here
                myButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
            }

            public void bindView(int pos) {
                // Set the items here with specific array elements you have

                myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()     {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Here's what you want to do when your list item is clicked
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ViewProduit.class);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                        String tid = map.get("ref").toString();
                        intent.putExtra("ref", tid);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        // Now define the viewholder for Normal list item
        public class NormalViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
            public NormalViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View v;

            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);

            NormalViewHolder vh = new NormalViewHolder(v);

            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            try {
                if (holder instanceof NormalViewHolder) {
                    NormalViewHolder vh = (NormalViewHolder) holder;
                    vh.bindView(position);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            if (list != null)
                return list.size();
            else return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return super.getItemViewType(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I tried to use this code with mine but I feel a bit lost :( I updated my post can you help me to correct it

Comment: Sorry I had a mistake in my example. The line should be `mAdapter = new MyAdapter();` as `MyAdapter` takes no argument. And from your logcat, I've seen that you're trying to use `myArrayList`. Listen, I just've added `myArrayList` for my example. You need to have your own `ArrayList` to serve your purpose which is `list` in your case. I'm updating my answer again though. See if that helps.