# Heterogenous Layouts inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cursoradapter

I am developing a weather app in which i wanted to use two `Views` inside `RecyclerView` which is having `CursorAdapter` as its member. I want to use one `View` to display todays weather and other view to display other days weathers. My `RecyclerView` is working perfectly if I only use one `View` to display weather. I have also overwritten `getItemViewType()?  to get to know which`View` type I should inflate.

Code for `getItemViewType()`:

```
private static int VIEW_TYPE_TODAY = 0;
private static int VIEW_TYPE_FUTURE_DAY = 1;

@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position == VIEW_TYPE_TODAY)
            return VIEW_TYPE_TODAY;
        else
            return VIEW_TYPE_FUTURE_DAY;
}
```

Code for the `newView()` of `CursorAdapter` which I have overwritten:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());
    int layoutId = -1;
    if(viewType==VIEW_TYPE_TODAY)
        layoutId = R.layout.list_item_forecast_today;
    else if(viewType==VIEW_TYPE_FUTURE_DAY)
        layoutId = R.layout.list_item_forecast;
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
    return view;
}
```

No matter what the value of `position` in `getItemViewType()` is, the function is always returning `VIEW_TYPE_TODAY`.

Can some please tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you can't use a `CursorAdapter` with a `RecyclerView`

Comment: Yes i can use CursorAdapter with a RecyclerView @Blackbelt

Comment: You can see these links [StackOverFlow ans](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27732748/6541898) , [GitHub link](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59)

Answer (score 1):

overriding `getItemViewType` is not enough to have a ListView with heterogeneous rows. You need to override  `getViewTypeCount()` as well, in order to return the number of heterogeneous rows you want to have (2 in your case). Please remember that your `getItemViewType` has to return continuos integers in the range `[0, getViewTypeCount() -1]`

Comment: Thanks,but now instead of today weather tomorrow weather is inflating the Layout list_item_forecast_today because cursor.getPosition() is returning -1 instead of 0

Comment: it is a bug in your current implementation. Overriding `getViewTypeCount` won't change the normal behaviour

Comment: hey check out my code for recycler view adapter and please point out the bug in my implementation [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309177/recyclerview-not-correctly-displaying-heterogenous-layouts)

Comment: how are you loading the cursor?

Comment: i am loading the cursor using loaders

Comment: `cursor.getPosition()` is returning -1 ? Try adding `if (cursor.getPosition() == -1) { cursor.moveToFirst(); }` as first thing in `newView` and check if it behaves correctly

Comment: Now today weather is getting the correct layout but tomorrow and some random days are also getting the layout designed for today weather

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://medium.com/@alebipin37/heteregenous-recyclerview-android-6d93b5ba3ff4) is the nice example of  heterogenous recyclerview. I am not posting as solution but for those who are looking for this kind of recyclerview.Hope it helps.

Comment: If not an answer it's likely better suited as a comment.