# Doubts about RecyclerView with CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-cursoradapter

I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517855/using-the-recyclerview-with-a-database) about RecyclerViews and Cursor adapters and I'm trying to use the first [solution](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59). I'm confused about the implementation of OnViewHolder function. I understood that OnViewHolder could be called by (ViewHolder, int) or (ViewHolder, Cursor) but I don't know how to use it with my project.

This is my original Adapter

```
public class FeedAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

/*
Etiqueta de Depuración
 */
private static final String TAG = FeedAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * View holder para evitar multiples llamadas de findViewById()
 */
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView titulo;
    TextView descripcion;

    int tituloI;
    int descripcionI;
}

public FeedAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);

}

public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();

    // Almacenar referencias
    vh.titulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
    vh.descripcion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);

    // Setear indices
    vh.tituloI = cursor.getColumnIndex(ScriptDatabase.ColumnEntradas.TITULO);
    vh.descripcionI = cursor.getColumnIndex(ScriptDatabase.ColumnEntradas.DESCRIPCION);

    view.setTag(vh);

    return view;
}

public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    final ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    // Setear el texto al titulo
    vh.titulo.setText(cursor.getString(vh.tituloI));

    // Obtener acceso a la descripción y su longitud
    vh.descripcion.setText(descripcion);

}
}
```

My new adapter with RecyclerView. OnBindViewHolder is unfinished because I don't know how set it.

```
public class RVAdapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<RVAdapter.ViewHolder>{
private Cursor mCursorAdapter;

public RVAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
    super(context,cursor);
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    TextView titulo;
    TextView descripcion;

    int tituloI;
    int descripcionI;

    public ViewHolder (View view){
        super(view);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        titulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        descripcion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(itemView);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    mCursorAdapter.moveToPosition(position);

    final ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

}
}
```

Should I use "onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor)" in this case? How could I make it works?

**EDIT 1**

This is the abstract class that extends my RVAdapter

```
public abstract class CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

private Context mContext;

private Cursor mCursor;

private boolean mDataValid;

private int mRowIdColumn;

private DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver;

public CursorRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    mContext = context;
    mCursor = cursor;
    mDataValid = cursor != null;
    mRowIdColumn = mDataValid ? mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id") : -1;
    mDataSetObserver = new NotifyingDataSetObserver();
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
    }
}

public Cursor getCursor() {
    return mCursor;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (mDataValid && mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        return mCursor.getLong(mRowIdColumn);
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
    super.setHasStableIds(true);
}

public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, Cursor cursor);

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, int position) {
    if (!mDataValid) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
    }
    if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
    }
    onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, mCursor);
}

/**
 * Change the underlying cursor to a new cursor. If there is an existing cursor it will be
 * closed.
 */
public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    Cursor old = swapCursor(cursor);
    if (old != null) {
        old.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Swap in a new Cursor, returning the old Cursor.  Unlike
 * {@link #changeCursor(Cursor)}, the returned old Cursor is <em>not</em>
 * closed.
 */
public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
    if (newCursor == mCursor) {
        return null;
    }
    final Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
    if (oldCursor != null && mDataSetObserver != null) {
        oldCursor.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
    }
    mCursor = newCursor;
    if (mCursor != null) {
        if (mDataSetObserver != null) {
            mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
        mRowIdColumn = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
        mDataValid = true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        mRowIdColumn = -1;
        mDataValid = false;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        //There is no notifyDataSetInvalidated() method in RecyclerView.Adapter
    }
    return oldCursor;
}

private class NotifyingDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        super.onChanged();
        mDataValid = true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
        super.onInvalidated();
        mDataValid = false;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        //There is no notifyDataSetInvalidated() method in RecyclerView.Adapter
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use your ViewHolder and position to access your views and fields like 
below:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        StructName name = names.get(position);
        viewHolder.txttitle.setText(name.title);
        viewHolder.rootItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

    }
```

It is easier than using cursor 
if that was helpful let me be aware.

Comment: Sorry for my delay. I realised that CursorRecyclerViewAdapter requires to implements onBindViewHolder with Cursors, but I don't get how to move positions with a Cursor variable. Any idea ? thanks so much for your interesting answer

Comment: I edited my original post with the abstract function CursorRecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

Use Cursor as it is more memory efficient.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    mCursorAdapter.moveToPosition(position);
    viewHolder.titulo.setText(mCursorAdapter.getString(mCursorAdapter.getColumnIndex(ScriptDatabase.ColumnEntradas.TITULO)));
    viewHolder.descripcion.setText(mCursorAdapter.getString(mCursorAdapter.getColumnIndex(ScriptDatabase.ColumnEntradas.DESCRIPCION)));
}
```

Comment: If I use cursors, position cannot be int but Cursor type and moveToPostion  have to be used with a int variable. How can I move positions with a Cursor type?

public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor)

Comment: What I meant is to use a cursor class member in your class(something that you've already done, the mCursorAdapter member) and not use an array/list of objects as HPbyP suggests. The "names.get(position);" he wrote implies that you have a list class member. Don't go for a solution like this, instead use your mCursorAdapter.
As for the RVAdapter.onBindViewHolder method its signature must be public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int).